# Using Load Balancer to redirect traffic through different tech stack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, azure, amazon-elb, azure-load-balancer

I currently have a website (single domain) hosted on several servers.
We use a load balancer to redirect traffic to the servers accordingly.
Currently we have a simple tech stack based on ASP.net and C#.
We would like to migrate our website progressively (feature by feature) to another tech stack based on React.
Knowing that we would like to keep our single domain, users should be redirected to a server or another depending on the path in the URL. For example homepage will be built on ASP.net, Feature 1 on React and Feature 2 on ASP.net.
I was wondering if we could use a Azure load balancers (Or Elastic Load Balancer if Azure cannot do it) to redirect traffic to one or the other tech stack depending on the incoming request.
For example:
- www.mywebsite.com will redirect to tech stack 1 based on .net
- www.mywebsite.com/feature1 will redirect to tech stack 2 based on React
- www.mywebsite.com/feature2 will redirect to tech stack 1

To go further, I was also wondering if on top of that I could use a central load balancer and 2 internal loadbalancers.
The public loadbalancer will capture all the requests. One internal loadbalncer will be for the tech stack 1 and the other one for the tech stack 2. The central  loadbalancer will redirect the traffic to the internal loadbalancers with the same principles as the one mentioned above.

For example:
- www.mywebsite.com will redirect to Load Balancer 1
- www.mywebsite.com/feature1 will redirect to Load Balancer 2
- www.mywebsite.com/feature2 will redirect to Load Balancer 1

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a nice fit for an Azure Application Gateway. Basically have application gateway accept all the calls and route to different backends based on the path in the request

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/url-route-overview